# Execute code if condition is true else make the condition true

Tags: php

I want to execute the code if the condition is true, else make the condition true and then execute the same code..

My code is..

```
$a = array(5,6,7,8,9);
$r = array_rand($a);
$b = 7;
if($b != $r)
  //do something
else
{
//here i want to select another random value and 
//execute the if else loop again until the if satisfies....
}
```

I already use with **goto**, can you suggest any alternative solution.

I think the problem is simple bu I can't make a solution.

How can I do this...Any help is great...

Comment: This is that `while` loops are for.

Comment: @JCOC611 can you explain how?? It will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
$a = array(5,6,7,8,9);
$r = array_rand($a);
$b = 7;
while($b != $r)
{
  //do something
 $r = array_rand($a);
}
```

Comment: This goes to infinite loop. Execute it and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = array(5,6,7,8,9);
$b = 7;
$r = array_rand($a);
while($b != $a[$r]) {
    $r = array_rand($a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is useless if you want this

> I want to execute the code if the condition is true, else make the condition true and then execute the same code..

All you need is

```
$a = array(5,6,7,8,9);
$b = 7;
$r=$b;  // That is exactly what your requirement is as it is stated.

//$r = $a[array_search($b,$a)];   this is also useless
```

That is because you are providing both the values for the condition. Whats the point in `rand` then? You know which value you want to select, `rand` is unnecessary.

The other answers do give you a workaround to what you want to do but they don't notice the basic premise and requirement of the question itself is wrong.

What's the point in saying keep finding a random value until the random value is 7?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(5,6,7,8,9);
$r = array_rand($a);
$b = 7;
if($b != $r)
{
  //do something
echo $r;

}else
{
echo "select another random value";
//here i want to select another random value and 
//execute the if else loop again until the if satisfies....
}
```

Comment: would you please format your code before posting it? indentation etc. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Just use this:

```
$a = array(5,6,7,8,9);
$b = 7;
$r = array_rand($a);

while($b != $r) {
    $r = array_rand($a);
}

  //do something
```

Comment: Just one correction, please add * $r = array_rand($a); * before while loop as well or else it will give error for $r.

Comment: This goes to infinite loop. Execute it and check.